# No module named 'django' when trying to import Django into Scrapy

Tags: django, scrapy

This is my folder structure:

```
root:
|--Django_project
|--|-- db_app
|--|-- Django_project
|--|-- manage.py
|--Scrapy_project
|--|--Scrapy_project
|--|--|--spiders
|--|--|--settings.py
|--|--|--pipelines.py
|--|--|--items.py
|--|--|--middlewares.py
|--|--scrapy.cfg
```

In `settings.py` I have this:

```py
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('.')))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Django_project.settings'

import django
django.setup()
```

I've tried every possible path, including an absolute path to the project root, to the Django project, to the Django app - nothing works and I get this:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

I should probably clarify that I'm running in a virtual environment.

Comment: Try installing `django`. `import django` means importing the django module, not the django project you have created. I you are sure you have installed django, check with your environments

Comment: Command for installing django - 'python -m pip install django'

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG I already did that in order to create the Django project, see the Django_project folder

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG I can also see "django" in root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages

Comment: Are you sure both modules (Django and Scrapy) are, both, installed in the same python virtual environment?